# Sliding a div under another div, when they have partial opacity

Tags: css, menu, opacity

I have the following problem: I have a horizontal menu with a sub-menu beneath it. I want the sub-menu to slide up under the main menu. Normally this would be no problem at all, just have the sub-menu on a lower z-index and move it up. BUT in this case both the menu and sub-menu have partial opacity. As things stand now when I move the sub-menu up you can still see it showing through the main nav.

What I need to do is as the sub-menu moves up make the part of it that's under the main menu invisible.

There's an animated gif showing the correct behavior and appearance at https://i.stack.imgur.com/1n4jJ.gif

Any ideas? Thanks!

**[ADDITION]**

Here's my demo code. The CSS:

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/jGlzr.png') no-repeat 0 0 scroll;
}
#topmenu {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
}

#submenu {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  top: 50px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
  border-top: 1px solid #666666;
}
#main {
  position: relative;
  top: 60px;
}
```

And the HTML:

```
<body>
  <div id="topmenu">Menu 1 | Menu 2 | Menu 3 | Menu 4</div>
  <div id="submenu">Sub menu 1 | Sub menu 2 | Sub menu 3 | Sub menu 4</div>
  <div id="main">
    <h1>Here is the main content!</h1>
    <p><strong>Notice how when you scroll this page the sub menu is still visible under the main menu? I need it to be clipped as it moves under the main menu. *AND* I want to do this without JavaScript. It's OK to see the main text under the main nav.</strong></p>

    <h2>Here's an animated gif that hopefully shows what I'm after...</h2>
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/1n4jJ.gif" alt="sliding nav demo" />
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consecetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Nam liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option congue nihil imperdiet doming id quod mazim placerat facer possim assum. Typi non habent claritatem insitam; est usus legentis in iis qui facit eorum claritatem. Investigationes demonstraverunt lectores legere me lius quod ii legunt saepius. Claritas est etiam processus dynamicus, qui sequitur mutationem consuetudium lectorum.</p>

    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Nam liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option congue nihil imperdiet doming id quod mazim placerat facer possim assum. Typi non habent claritatem insitam; est usus legentis in iis qui facit eorum claritatem. Investigationes demonstraverunt lectores legere me lius quod ii legunt saepius. Claritas est etiam processus dynamicus, qui sequitur mutationem consuetudium lectorum.</p>

    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Nam liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option congue nihil imperdiet doming id quod mazim placerat facer possim assum. Typi non habent claritatem insitam; est usus legentis in iis qui facit eorum claritatem. Investigationes demonstraverunt lectores legere me lius quod ii legunt saepius. Claritas est etiam processus dynamicus, qui sequitur mutationem consuetudium lectorum.</p>
  </div>

</body>
```

I've now tossed demo code up on JSFiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/chrisspurgeon/6ddWz/ . It has the correct behavior EXCEPT that the part of the sub-nav that's under the main nav should be invisible, and the translucency of the main nav should not be effected.

Comment: Please post the relevant code, preferably in a JSFiddle :)

Comment: Sure thing! There's a fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/chrisspurgeon/6ddWz/ . This does what I want EXCEPT the sub-menu can't show under the main menu.

Answer (score 0):

This example isn't exact, but it should put you in the right direction: [Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CYEDx/1/)

HTML

```
<div id="header">Hover this.
    <div id="drop">Drop content here</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#drop {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
    color: white;
    height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    -webkit-transition: all .8s ease;
    -moz-transition: all .8s ease;
    -ms-transition: all .8s ease;
    -o-transition: all .8s ease;
    transition: all .8s ease;
    position: absolute;

}
```

To hide on scroll

```
$(function(){
    $(window).scroll(function() { 
        if ($(this).scrollTop() > 0) { 
            $("#drop").css('height', '0');

        } 
        else {     
            $("#drop").css('height', '20px');
        }  
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks! That's close, but the sub-nav has to move up when the page is scrolled. I've added example code above.

Comment: Hi, I added some JS and updated the fiddle to show you a scrolling example for the code.

Comment: Thanks! I was really hoping to do this with pure CSS, no JavaScript. But I'm thinking I have no choice.

Comment: There isn't a scrollTop equivalent for css that I know of for css. If this resolves your issue, I would appreciate consideration as marking this answer correct

Answer (score 0):

you must set the `z-index` value for both divs and,you must give the lower div a greater `z-index` value,also you must set the overflow of the bottom div to visible.

example:

```
.upperdiv {z-index:5;}
.bottomdiv {z-index:100;overflow:visible;}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I don't think that does it. I've added example code and a JSFiddle link to my question, see if that makes it clearer.

Answer (score 0):

There are two things at work here.

### 1. Z-indexing

The topmenu needs to be rendered **above** the submenu in the stack. Right now because of simple HTML ordering, your submenu is being rendered above the topmenu.

We fix this with z-indexing:

```
#topmenu
{
    z-index: 999;
}

#submenu
{
    z-index: 998;
}
```

---

### 2. Opacity

In the example you provided ([this GIF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1n4jJ.gif)), the topmenu has a fully opaque background. In order to completely hide the submenu when it passes behind the topmenu, we **need<sup>1</sup>** to have a fully opaque background:

```
#topmenu
{
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
}
```

### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6ddWz/1/)

---

#### Footnotes:

1: This is only if you want a JS-free solution. If you will allow JS, there are solutions that will allow you to use partially transparent backgrounds.